# PASO DE INFORMACION ENTRE VENTANAS TKINTER MEDIANTE FUNCIONES

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo algunos errores en el paso de informacion mediantes funciones y uso de ventanas con Tkinter. He simplificado el codigo solo para enfocar la pregunta al problema.
Tengo las dos funciones que crean ventanas:
La funcion de ventana 2 se le envia un objeto y deseo que cuando se cierre la ventana la funcion me retorne la variable booliana "guardarInformacion" si el usuario la cerro mediante el boton GUARDAR. Las fucniones son las siguientes:

```
def funcionVentana2(objeto):
    ventana = tkinter.Toplevel()
    ventana.title("Ventana 2")
    # Variables
    guardarInformacion = False

    # Funciones
    def funcionBotonGuardar():
        global guardarInformacion
        # Codigo que actualiza las variables de "objeto" con datos ingresado por el usuario en los widget de la ventana
        # ...
        # ...
        guardarInformacion = True
        ventana.destroy()

    # Widget
    botonGuardar = ttk.Button(ventana, text="Guardar", command=funcionBotonGuardar)
    botonGuardar.pack()
    botonCancelar = ttk.Button(ventana, text="Cancelar", command=ventana.destroy)
    botonCancelar.pack()
    # Otros Widget que muestran la información de "objeto"
    # ...
    # Mainloop
    ventana.mainloop()

    return guardarInformacion
```

Y tengo la ventana 1 que llama a la funcion que construye la ventana 2 y que una vez reciba que el usuario cerro la ventana 2 mediante el boton guardar, agregue la informacion de "Objeto" a una lista donde se van almacenando la informacion.

```
def funcionVentana1():
    ventana = tkinter.Tk()
    ventana.title("Ventana 1")

    # Funciones
    def funcionBotonVentana2():
        # materiales es un modulo.py donde se ha creado las clases MaterialConcreto y la variable LISTAMATERIALESCONCRETO
        objeto = materiales.MaterialConcreto()
        guardarInformacion = funcionVentana2(objeto)
        print(guardarInformacion)
        if guardarInformacion:
            # los atributos de objeto fueron actualizados en el boton guardar de la ventana 2
            materiales.LISTAMATERIALESCONCRETO.agregarmaterial(objeto.get_nombre(),
                                                               objeto.get_pesoEsp(),
                                                               objeto.get_E(),
                                                               objeto.get_poisson(),
                                                               objeto.get_fc(),
                                                               objeto.get_ecu(),
                                                               objeto.get_lamda()
                                                               )

    # Widget
    botonVentana2 = ttk.Button(ventana, text="Abrirventana2", command=funcionBotonVentana2)
    botonVentana2.pack()
    # Otros Widget que muestran la información de "objeto"
    # ...
    # Mainloop
    ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PROBLEMA 1:**
Cuando abro la ventana 2 y la cierro mediante el Boton GUARDAR no se retorna nada de la funcion en tiempo de ejecucion (Lo compruebo con el print(guardarInformacion)). Solo hasta cuando se cierra todo la ejecucion del programa (Ventana 1 y venatana 2) retorna de un solo todas las veces que le di guardar.

**PROBLEMA 2:**
Dentro de la fucion "funcionBotonGuardar()" de la ventana 2 no se esta actualizando la variable guardarInformacion = True porque siempre retorna False a pesar que defini la variable "guardarInformacion" como global dentro de la funcion.

¿ que puede estar funcionando mal ?

Muchas Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

PD: al principio trabaje ventanas mediante Programacion Orientada Objetos pero una vez se cierran, ¿ como podria saber y si se cerraron con el boton guardar ? y como podria recibir la informacion digitada en las ventanas ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre solucion investigando varias preguntas en ingles.

La solucion es:

1. Cambiar el mainloop() de la ventana Toplevel por wait_window()
2. Agregar "global guardarInformacion" en el ambito de la funcion funcionVentana2().